# Why does $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \left[ \frac{1}{(2z + 2n)^2} + \frac{1}{(2z + 2n + 1)^2} - \frac{1}{(2z + n)^2} \right] = 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am reading a textbook, and it uses the equation

> $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2z + 2n)^2} + \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2z + 2n + 1)^2} = \sum_{m = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2z + m)^2}$.

Could someone tell me why this is true?  I am pretty clueless...

Comment: Every non-negative integer $m$ is either even ($m = 2n$) or odd ($m = 2n+1$). [And the series are absolutely convergent for $-2z \notin \mathbb{N}$, so you can split it up.]

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you.